# Modernizr.js and page loading performance

Tags: performance, modernizr, browser-detection, feature-detection

I'm trying to decide whether it might make sense to use modernizr.js.

Does covering all the edge cases that modernizer.js does significantly affect page load speed?

thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you download Modernizr, you can customize it to only include the functionality that you need.

http://modernizr.com/download/

That should cover any performance concerns.

Comment: This is not answer for question.